# HTTParty fails sending long JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rubygems, httparty

I'm using HTTParty to send data to a remote API via POST, I have to send a JSON file and it works fine. The problem is when the JSON is too long, Httparty returns an error like the API is not working but if I try the same petition in Postman everything works fine.

This is my petition:

```
def self.resolver_expresion(expresion)
    @peticion = "{\n  \"peticion\": {\n    \"TokenSesion\": \"XXXXXXXXXXX\", \n    \"Expresion\": \"#{expresion}\"\n  }\n}"
    # Rails.logger.info @peticion
    @result = HTTParty.post(
                'http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX/SvcGGb2b.svc/EvaluarExpresion',
               :body => @peticion,
                headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Accept' => 'application/json' }
              )
  end
```

The "expresion" variable is too long. If I made this petition a little bit shorter the service works fine. This is an example of the content of that variable:

```
IIF(003050=0,'BASE1;Base para foliar;BLANC;Blanco;BM572;Blanco Mate C572;BRONC;Bronce;F1001;Fol.1001;F1002;Fol.1002;FBRON;Fol.Bronce;FX912;Fol.Bronce FX-91293714;FME06;Fol.Caoba;FME08;Fol.Cerezo;FCRWE;Fol.CremeWeiss F456-5001;FME02;Fol.Golden;FGOIN;Fol.Golden Interior;FE004;Fol.Gris 7012;fe007;Fol.Gris 7016083 liso;FE005;Fol.Gris Antracita 7016;FME05;Fol.Macore;FE006;Fol.Marrón Oscuro;FE002;Fol.Negro Asfalto;FME01;Fol.Nogal Claro;FNOIN;Fol.Nogal Osc. Interior;FME03;Fol.Nogal Oscuro;FMI01;Fol.Pino Nudo Interior;FMI02;Fol.Roble Interior;FME04;Fol.Roble Oscuro;FMI03;Fol.Sapely Claro Interior;FME07;Fol.Sapely Douglas;FSAMO;Fol.Sapely Moca Interior;FMI05;Fol.Sapely Oscuro Interior;FME10;Fol.Siena Noce;FME09;Fol.Siena Rosso;FTEKA;Fol.Teka Interior;FE001;Fol.Verde 6009;FWEIN;Fol.Wenge Interior;FME11;Fol.Winchester;GRAFI;Grafito;GRIS;Gris;INOX;Inox;1015R;R.1015;3005R;R.3005;3007R;R.3007;5010R;R.5010;6005R;R.6005;6009R;R.6009;7011R;R.7011;7012R;R.7012;7016R;R.7016;7022R;R.7022;7030R;R.7030;7040R;R.7040;8007R;R.8007;8014R;R.8014;8017R;R.8017;8017V;R.8017 Vasco;8019R;R.8019;9011R;R.9011;BLWIN;WIN-BLANCO;3FGOL;3F Golden Interior;3FNOS;3F Nogal Osc. Interior;BLANG;Blanco \"G\";F4367;Fol. F-436-7003;F1004;Fol.1004;F1005;Fol.1005;F1006;Fol.1006;F3069;Fol.30690.41-167;FE009;Fol.7012083 liso;FE008;Fol.7021083 liso;F7038;Fol.7038083 Liso;FBLAN;Fol.9001 Blanco Viejo;FABED;Fol.Abedul;F5053;Fol.Altweiss F456-5053;ALX80;Fol.ALX - 80;ALXRA;Fol.ALX - RA;ALXRG;Fol.ALX - RG;ALXRM;Fol.ALX - RM;ALXRS;Fol.ALX - RS;ALXTK;Fol.ALX - TK;ALXWE;Fol.ALX - WE;FANTE;Fol.Anteak;F5007;Fol.Azul 5007;F5011;Fol.Azul 5011;F5030;Fol.Azul 5030;F5013;Fol.Azul Cobalto 5013;FAZ06;Fol.Azul F-436-5006;F7023;Fol.B Grau 7023;FBASA;Fol.Basaltgralu F-436-7048;FBEIG;Fol.Beige F456-5015;FOL32;Fol.Black Cherry 3202 001167;F9010;Fol.Blanco 9010;FBLPU;Fol.Blanco Puro FX021291014168;F.BLC;Fol.Blancocrema 137905-167;FBRAU;Fol.Braun Dekor 851805-167;FBRUS;Fol.Brush R69;FCANA;Fol.Canadian;FCEDR;Fol.Cedro Gris;FCENI;Fol.Ceniza ASH C-35 FX;FCHER;Fol.Cherry Amarento 4363043;F.CRE;Fol.CremeWeiss 1379 05-167;CRPLT;Fol.Crown Platin 9.1293 001-119500;F9294;Fol.Crystal White 9294;FDESI;Fol.Dekor Sierra Genarbt 2167009-116700;FDUNK;Fol.Eiche Dunkel 2052089-167;FEIHE;Fol.Eiche Hell;FEICH;Fol.Eiche Nature;EIRUS;Fol.Eiche Rustikal 3149-008-167;F1012;Fol.F-436-1012;F1014;Fol.F-436-1014;F5054;Fol.F4565054 Creme;FE003;Fol.Gris 7001;F7004;Fol.Gris 7004083 Liso;F7035;Fol.Gris 7035083 Liso;F7251;Fol.Gris 7035-7251;F3983;Fol.Gris 7039-05-083 Liso;F7039;Fol.Gris 7039-05-167;F7155;Fol.Gris 7155;FGFOR;Fol.Gris Forja (49122 Cova);F1017;Fol.Gris S56 F436-1017;FGRSO;Fol.Gris Sombra MX701605;FINDI;Fol.Indian;FIRIS;Fol.Irish Oak 3211005-148;F-436;Fol.M.Oscuro F436-5011;FM-MO;Fol.Madera Oscuro;FX121;Fol.Marfil FX-21211028.83;F5056;Fol.Marfil Tex. F456-5056;MABRA;Fol.Maronenbraun F4265025;F8016;Fol.Marron 8016;FMONT;Fol.Montana Eiche Tabak;FNOSO;Fol.Noce Sorrento Natur;FNUEZ;Fol.Nuez Terra 436-3059;FOBRO;Fol.Oak Brown S27 F436-3087;FOREG;Fol.Oregon 4 1192-001-167;FO436;Fol.Oregon F436-2009;FOORO;Fol.Oro F-436-1007;PNUEX;Fol.P. Nudo Ext. F426-2047;PIMON;Fol.Pino Montaña 3069041167;FPLAV;Fol.Plata V FX-02-12-76-000014;FPYRI;Fol.Pyrite R48 EXOFOL FX;FQUAR;Fol.Quarz Platin 9.1293.002;FGRAU;Fol.QuarzGrau 703905-116700;FROIR;Fol.Roble Irlan. 005-114800;FE032;Fol.Roble Pantanoso;FRPKM;Fol.Roble Pantanoso Komerling;F3003;Fol.Rojo 3003-05-167;F3005;Fol.Rojo 3005;F3011;Fol.Rojo 3011 Ref.308105-167;F3081;Fol.Rojo 3081 R13;FRCHE;Fol.Rustic Cherry;FOLSA;Fol.Sapely;49198;Fol.shoogun 49198;SHOAD;Fol.Shoogun AD 49195;FSHOG;Fol.Shoogun Montana 49197;FSKAI;Fol.SKAI 7003;F5150;Fol.Stahlblau 5150;FTROM;Fol.Trompet Renolit;F6005;Fol.Verde 6005;FOLVF;Fol.Verde Forja Cova 49110;FWEIS;Fol.Weiss 915205-168;S2800;Gris 2800 Sable;ORO;Oro;1000R;R.1000;1001R;R.1001;1002R;R.1002;1003R;R.1003;1004R;R.1004;1005R;R.1005;1006R;R.1006;1007R;R.1007;1010R;R.1010;1011R;R.1011;1012R;R.1012;1013R;R.1013;1014R;R.1014;1016R;R.1016;1017R;R.1017;1018R;R.1018;1019R;R.1019;1020R;R.1020;1021R;R.1021;1023R;R.1023;1024R;R.1024;1026R;R.1026;1027R;R.1027;1028R;R.1028;1032R;R.1032;1033R;R.1033;1034R;R.1034;1035R;R.1035;1036R;R.1036;1037R;R.1037;2000R;R.2000;2001R;R.2001;2002R;R.2002;2003R;R.2003;2004R;R.2004;2005R;R.2005;2007R;R.2007;2008R;R.2008;2009R;R.2009;2010R;R.2010;2011R;R.2011;2012R;R.2012;2013R;R.2013;3000R;R.3000;3001R;R.3001;3002R;R.3002;3003R;R.3003;T3003;R.3003 Texturado;3004R;R.3004;3009R;R.3009;3011R;R.3011;3012R;R.3012;3013R;R.3013;3014R;R.3014;3015R;R.3015;3016R;R.3016;3017R;R.3017;3018R;R.3018;3020R;R.3020;3022R;R.3022;3024R;R.3024;3026R;R.3026;3027R;R.3027;3031R;R.3031;3032R;R.3032;3033R;R.3033;4001R;R.4001;4002R;R.4002;4003R;R.4003;4004R;R.4004;4005R;R.4005;4006R;R.4006;4007R;R.4007;4008R;R.4008;4009R;R.4009;4010R;R.4010;4011R;R.4011;4012R;R.4012;5000R;R.5000;5001R;R.5001;5002R;R.5002;5003R;R.5003;5004R;R.5004;5005R;R.5005;5007R;R.5007;5008R;R.5008;5009R;R.5009;5011R;R.5011;5012R;R.5012;5013R;R.5013;5014R;R.5014;5015R;R.5015;5017R;R.5017;5018R;R.5018;5019R;R.5019;5020R;R.5020;5021R;R.5021;5022R;R.5022;5023R;R.5023;5024R;R.5024;5025R;R.5025;5026R;R.5026;6000R;R.6000;6001R;R.6001;6002R;R.6002;6003R;R.6003;6004R;R.6004;6006R;R.6006;6007R;R.6007;6008R;R.6008;M6009;R.6009 Mate;6010R;R.6010;6011R;R.6011;6012R;R.6012;M6012;R.6012 Mate;6013R;R.6013;6014R;R.6014;6015R;R.6015;6016R;R.6016;6017R;R.6017;6018R;R.6018;6019R;R.6019;6020R;R.6020;6021R;R.6021;6022R;R.6022;6024R;R.6024;6025R;R.6025;6026R;R.6026;6027R;R.6027;6028R;R.6028;6029R;R.6029;6032R;R.6032;6033R;R.6033;6034R;R.6034;6035R;R.6035;6036R;R.6036;7000R;R.7000;7001R;R.7001;7002R;R.7002;7003R;R.7003;7004R;R.7004;7005R;R.7005;7006R;R.7006;7008R;R.7008;7009R;R.7009;7010R;R.7010;7013R;R.7013;7015R;R.7015;7021R;R.7021;7023R;R.7023;7024R;R.7024;7026R;R.7026;7031R;R.7031;7032R;R.7032;7033R;R.7033;7034R;R.7034;7035R;R.7035;7036R;R.7036;7037R;R.7037;7038R;R.7038;7039R;R.7039;7040R;R.7040;7042R;R.7042;7043R;R.7043;7044R;R.7044;7045R;R.7045;7046R;R.7046;7047R;R.7047;7048R;R.7048;8000R;R.8000;8001R;R.8001;8002R;R.8002;8003R;R.8003;8004R;R.8004;8007R;R.8007;8008R;R.8008;8011R;R.8011;8012R;R.8012;8015R;R.8015;8016R;R.8016;8022R;R.8022;8023R;R.8023;8024R;R.8024;8025R;R.8025;8028R;R.8028;8029R;R.8029;9001R;R.9001;9002R;R.9002;9003R;R.9003;9004R;R.9004;9005R;R.9005;9006R;R.9006;9007R;R.9007;9016R;R.9016;9017R;R.9017;9018R;R.9018;9022R;R.9022;9023R;R.9023','BLANC;Blanco;BM572;Blanco Mate C572;BRONC;Bronce;BRUTO;BRUTO;BFOGO;Fol.Bic.golden/blanco;BFONO;Fol.Bic.nogal/blanco;FME02;Fol.Golden;FME03;Fol.Nogal Oscuro;GRAFI;Grafito;INOX;Inox;LEMTX;Lac.Embero Texturado;LM19;Lac.Golden;LM27;Lac.Nogal Andaluz;LANO7;Lac.Nogal Osc. 7/9104-402;LM12;Lac.Nogal Oscuro;LM14;Lac.Pino Nudo;LM13;Lac.Teka;ORO;Oro;PLATA;Plata;PT103;Plata grat. Rep. 103;1015R;R.1015;3005R;R.3005;3007R;R.3007;5010R;R.5010;6005R;R.6005;6009R;R.6009;7011R;R.7011;7012R;R.7012;7016R;R.7016;7022R;R.7022;8007R;R.8007;8014R;R.8014;8017R;R.8017;8017V;R.8017 Vasco;8019R;R.8019;9011M;R.9011 Mate;007TX;007 Tex. RT-7246;5149L;5149-Lanoal;7132A;7132 Alucolor;9811A;9811 Alucolor;9G009;9G-009-A005;ACERO;Acero;ACIER;Acier SW-161D;A7137;Adapta RT-7137;ALE20;Alesta 3020 Text. AE03053302020;ALE16;Alesta 7016 Text. AE03057701620;ALE39;Alesta 7039 Text. AE03057703920;ALEGR;Alesta Gris Gran. AE03217045120;AN51G;Anod.51G Grata/Gris;AAZCO;Anod.Azul Gratado 53G;ABUCO;Anod.Burdeos Gratado 52G;AB52M;Anod.Burdeos Mate 52-M Cortizo;GGR55;Anod.Gris Grata R55;AN10M;Anod.Negro Mate 10-M Cortizo;ANOAZ;Azul Grat. Repulido;AZ081;Azul Grat. S/rep. 081;19906;Azul Texturado (YJ331/20);B8821;B8821;8821M;B8821 Mate C251;BCLSA;Beige Claro Satinado;TBECL;Beige Claro Texturado;BELIM;Beige Limestone - SD031C1007020;BEOSC;Beige Oscuro;19268;Blanco 19268/C;21110;Blanco 2110110;BLDUP;Blanco Dupond Mate;BLMAT;Blanco Mate;SA200;Blanco Mate SA-200-L;PAPTX;Blanco Papiro 9002 Tex.;SBLAN;Blanco Satinado;BLTEX;Blanco Tex. 9262;TBLAN;Blanco Texturado;B2600;Bleu 2600 Sable;B2700;Bleu 2700 Sable;B500S;Bleu 500 Sable;B600S;Bleu 600 Sable;B700S;Bleu 700 Sable;BLCAN;Bleu Canon;BR136;Bronce 136 Grat. Rep.;B136M;Bronce 136 Mate Aleman;BR34S;Bronce 34S;BR33G;Bronce aluarte 33-G Cortizo;BRBRI;Bronce Brillo Rep. 35S;C106B;BRONCE C106;BRCAM;Bronce Canarias Mate;BROCL;Bronce Claro;BGRRE;Bronce Grat. Rep. 33S;BRGSR;Bronce Grat. S/rep. 31S;LBRON;Bronce Lacado;BR138;Bronce Mate 138;BRMAT;Bronce Mate 30S;BRMTE;Bronce Mate Technal;BRREP;Bronce Repulido 34R;BRONZ;Bronze 2525YW283F;B2650;Brun 2650 Sable;B650S;Brun 650 Sable;ANOBU;Burdeos Grat. Repulido;C216F;C216-CANON FR;C209F;Canon SW 209 F;CHAMP;Champagne;SW251;Champagne SW251F;CITER;City Terracotta SD031C8021020;COFOR;Cobre Forja;EACLA;Earth Clay SD031C8005020;80081;Eisenglimmer 29/80081 Tiger;F1001;Fol.1001;F1002;Fol.1002;F1006;Fol.1006;FE009;Fol.7012/083 liso;FE008;Fol.7021/083 liso;FBLAN;Fol.9001 Blanco Viejo;F5007;Fol.Azul 5007;BFO16;Fol.Bic.7016 Liso/blanco;BFOBR;Fol.Bic.bronce/blanco;FBRON;Fol.Bronce;FX912;Fol.Bronce FX-91293714;FME06;Fol.Caoba;FME08;Fol.Cerezo;FCRWE;Fol.CremeWeiss F456-5001;FDUNK;Fol.Eiche Dunkel 2052089-167;FEICH;Fol.Eiche Nature;F1012;Fol.F-436-1012;FE003;Fol.Gris 7001;F7004;Fol.Gris 7004/083 Liso;FE004;Fol.Gris 7012;fe007;Fol.Gris 7016/083 liso;F7039;Fol.Gris 7039-05-167;FE005;Fol.Gris Antracita 7016;FGFOR;Fol.Gris Forja (49122 Cova);FININ;Fol.Inox 7048 Interior;FIRIS;Fol.Irish Oak 3211005-148;FME05;Fol.Macore;FE006;Fol.Marrón Oscuro;FE002;Fol.Negro Asfalto;FNOSO;Fol.Noce Sorrento Natur;FME01;Fol.Nogal Claro;FOORO;Fol.Oro F-436-1007;FMI01;Fol.Pino Nudo Interior;FO116;Fol.Pirita 116;FPYRI;Fol.Pyrite R48 EXOFOL FX;FMI02;Fol.Roble Interior;FME04;Fol.Roble Oscuro;FE032;Fol.Roble Pantanoso;FRPKM;Fol.Roble Pantanoso Komerling;F3005;Fol.Rojo 3005;FMI03;Fol.Sapely Claro Interior;FME07;Fol.Sapely Douglas;FMI05;Fol.Sapely Oscuro Interior;SHOAD;Fol.Shoogun AD 49195;FME10;Fol.Siena Noce;FME09;Fol.Siena Rosso;F6005;Fol.Verde 6005;FE001;Fol.Verde 6009;FOLVF;Fol.Verde Forja Cova 49110;FWERO;Fol.Weinrot 300505-167;FWEIS;Fol.Weiss 915205-168;FME11;Fol.Winchester;GHARD;Ghardaia 2525 YW253F;GOLPE;Gold Pearl YY217-E;P12J7;Grafito P12J75020 Titan;GRFAC;Green Factory SD031C6030020;GRCLA;Grey Classic 618 (68/71441);GR007;Gris 007;G150S;Gris 150 Sable;G2150;Gris 2150 Sable;G2400;Gris 2400 Sable;G2500;Gris 2500 Sable;S2800;Gris 2800 Sable;G2900;Gris 2900 Sable;29770;Gris 29770 Chine YX051F;G437S;Gris 437 Sable;G900S;Gris 900 sable;GRCEN;Gris Ceniza;G7815;Gris Forja 7815;G7107;Gris Forja RF-7107-XW;GALET;Gris Galet SXJ00F;GRGRA;Gris Granulado BG-161-S;GMERC;Gris Mercurio;B703L;GRIS METALIZADO DB703L;GM233;Gris Moteado 233V6607;GRMOT;Gris Moteado RT-7119-I;GRNIE;Gris Niebla;RA700;Gris Oxidon RA7000OX;GRPLO;Gris Plomo;GTXMT;Gris Tex. Met. 19073/1;SLA73;Gris Text. SLA73F;19903;Gris Texturado (YL354L/20);X7022;Gris TX-7022;H2525;Halamhera 2525 YW052F;IMMAD;Imitación Madera;IN063;Inox 063 Alugon;IN141;Inox 141;IN142;Inox 142;IN143;Inox 143;IN145;Inox 145;IN345;Inox Brillo Rep. 345;IN245;Inox Claro Brillo. Rep. 245;IN243;Inox Claro Gr. Rep. 243;IN242;Inox Claro Gr. S/rep. 242;IN241;Inox Claro Mate 241;IN246;Inox Claro Rep. 246;IN343;Inox Grat. Rep. 343;IN342;Inox Grat. S/rep. 342;IN341;Inox Mate 341;INREP;Inox Repulido 346;LM20;Lac.Acacia A-7;LACME;Lac.Acacia Media 617;LACCA;Lac.Acacia-Caoba;LM29;Lac.Afric;LM08;Lac.Aliso;ALITX;Lac.Aliso Texturado;L.ANT;Lac.Antracita;BLEFE;Lac.Blanco Effecta;BLMAD;Lac.Blanco Madera;BLEDA;Lac.Bleda;BLETX;Lac.Bleda Texturado;30898;Lac.Bronce C33 - 30898 Valspar;BRC33;Lac.Bronce C33 - 35565 Valspar;RX163;Lac.Bronce Italia RX-1634-XW;LM02;Lac.Castaño;LM10;Lac.Cedro;CEDB8;Lac.Cedro Text. B-8;CE317;Lac.Cerezo 317-7;CEALU;Lac.Cerezo Cat. Osc. 606;LM30;Lac.Cerezo Cat. Texturado;CT626;Lac.Cerezo Cat.Tex. 626;LM15;Lac.Cerezo Catedrales;LM04;Lac.Cerezo Dorado;LM06;Lac.Cerezo G-7;LCG7T;Lac.Cerezo G-7 Texturado;CE618;Lac.Cerezo Medit. 618;LCOIN;Lac.Cerezo Osc. L03-02 (Ingalza);CERTX;Lac.Cerezo Texturado 317-TX;LM17;Lac.Douglas Europeo P-8;LM24;Lac.Douglas G-8;LG8TX;Lac.Douglas G-8 Texturado;LM07;Lac.Embero;LM01;Lac.Haya;HA608;Lac.Haya 608;BTC10;Lac.Haya TXT BTC-100;LACIN;Lac.Inox;RX704;Lac.Inox RX-7048-XW;LINES;Lac.Inox RX-7187-XW;LINOX;Lac.Inox RX-7304-XW;MADBL;Lac.Madera Blanco;LM31;Lac.Malta Texturado;NANTX;Lac.Nog.And.Texturado;LNETX;Lac.Nog.Eur.Texturado;NOALU;Lac.Nogal 8007 Alucolor;LNAMK;Lac.Nogal Andalucia (MTAPTK);LM16;Lac.Nogal B-7;LB7TX;Lac.Nogal B-7 Texturado;LNOEF;Lac.Nogal Effecta;LM28;Lac.Nogal Europeo;LNOTX;Lac.Nogal O. Text. 7/9104-402;BTO-1;Lac.Nogal TXT Ref. BTO-1;LOLMO;Lac.Olmo;OLALU;Lac.Olmo Medit. 609;LM09;Lac.Pino Envejecido;PIETX;Lac.Pino Envejecido Texturado;LM23;Lac.Pino Mobila M-8;PN604;Lac.Pino Nudo Osc. 604;PNTEX;Lac.Pino Nudo Texturado;LM32;Lac.Pino SIN Nudo;LACPL;Lac.Plata;LRAIZ;Lac.Raiz BO-4;LRAD7;Lac.Raiz D-7  7/9154-404;LM05;Lac.Roble Assi;LM03;Lac.Roble E-7;LROTX;Lac.Roble E-7 Texturado;LM18;Lac.Roble K-8;RK8TX;Lac.Roble K-8 Texturado;ROMED;Lac.Roble Medio;ROBME;Lac.Roble Medio Texturado;LRPIR;Lac.Roble Pirineos Rugoso;RRBC2;Lac.Roble Rojo BC-2;LRRP8;Lac.Roble Rojo P-8;LP8TX;Lac.Roble Rojo P-8 Texturado;LM26;Lac.Roble Rústico;RR130;Lac.Roble Rústico FTO-130;RTBTO;Lac.Roble Text. BTO-5;LM21;Lac.Sapelly Burdeos;LM11;Lac.Sapelly Caoba;LBO12;Lac.Sapelly Caoba BO-12;LM22;Lac.Sapelly Marrón;SAP-T;Lac.Sapelly Terminal;LSCTX;Lac.Sapely Caoba Texturado;LS705;Lac.Sapely Rojizo S-705;SILBA;Lac.Silba Texturado;LT601;Lac.Teka Catedrales 601;TTXBG;Lac.Teka Tex. base Golden;TETEX;Lac.Teka Texturado;LTECL;Lac.Texturado Claro 627;LWENG;Lac.Wengue;LWETX;Lac.Wengue Texturado;M2525;Manganese 2525 YW280F;MANGA;Manganese SW-204F;MADIN;Marrón DINDE SW-208-F;MADUP;Marrón DUPOND;MAGRA;Marron Granulado;MAMAR;Marron Marmol Rohmhaas;RX220;Marron Mot. RX-220-L;MAMOT;Marron Moteado;MOSAT;Marrón Osc. Satinado;MOSTE;Marrón Osc. Texturado;MARSS;Mars 2525 Sable;SX350;Mars SX350F;MEASP;Metallic Asphalt SD031C4020020;NEGBR;Negro Brillo;C107N;Negro C107;NEANO;Negro Grat. Repulido;NE051;Negro Grat. S/rep. 051;NM050;Negro Mate Anod. 050;NETEX;Negro Tex. D-1094 Interpon;NESTO;Nestor - Adapta;N100S;Noir 100 Sable;N163C;Noir 163 Chine SXJ02F;N200S;Noir 200 Sable;N2100;Noir 2100 Sable;N2200;Noir 2200 Sable;N2300;Noir 2300 Sable YW383I;N900S;Noir 900 Sable;OCRTX;Ocre Texturado;OGRRE;Oro Grat. Rep. 023;OROMA;Oro Mate 020;ORREP;Oro Repulido 21R;OXICO;Oxicobre;OXITX;Oxidon Texturado (Sopena);PT105;Plata Brillo Rep. 105;PT105;Plata Brillo Rep. 105;C105P;PLATA C105;PT102;Plata grat. s/rep. 102;PLA-M;Plata Mate 101;PLMAL;Plata Mate Aleman;MW154;Plata MW 154 L;PLREP;Plata Repulido 106;P2525;Platine 2525 YW284F;SW203;Platine SW203F;PYRIT;Pyrite 2525 YW207F;XA05L;R. D1036 Marrón SXA05L/25;1000R;R.1000;M1000;R.1000 Mate;T1000;R.1000 Texturado;1001R;R.1001;1002R;R.1002;1003R;R.1003;1004R;R.1004;1005R;R.1005;1006R;R.1006;1007R;R.1007;1010R;R.1010;1011R;R.1011;M1011;R.1011 Mate;1012R;R.1012;1013R;R.1013;M1013;R.1013 Mate;S1013;R.1013 Satinado;YD313;R.1013 Tex. YD313F;1013T;R.1013 Texturado;1014R;R.1014;M1015;R.1015 Mate;RD615;R.1015 RD615L;S1015;R.1015 Satinado;T1015;R.1015 Texturado;1016R;R.1016;1017R;R.1017;1018R;R.1018;1019R;R.1019;M1019;R.1019 Mate;S1019;R.1019 Satinado;1020R;R.1020;1021R;R.1021;1023R;R.1023;1024R;R.1024;M1024;R.1024 Mate;1026R;R.1026;1027R;R.1027;1028R;R.1028;1032R;R.1032;1033R;R.1033;1034R;R.1034;1035R;R.1035;M1035;R.1035 Mate;SW240;R.1035 Mate SW240F;1036R;R.1036;M1036;R.1036 Mate;1037R;R.1037;1817R;R.1817 Blanco Mate;2000R;R.2000;2001R;R.2001;2002R;R.2002;2003R;R.2003;2004R;R.2004;2005R;R.2005;2007R;R.2007;2008R;R.2008;2009R;R.2009;2010R;R.2010;2011R;R.2011;2012R;R.2012;2013R;R.2013;3000R;R.3000;3001R;R.3001;3002R;R.3002;S3002;R.3002 Satinado;T3002;R.3002 Texturado;3003R;R.3003;T3003;R.3003 Texturado;3004R;R.3004;M3004;R.3004 Mate;S3004;R.3004 Satinado;TC561;R.3004 Texturado;M3005;R.3005 Mate;3005S;R.3005 Satinado;TC560;R.3005 Texturado;T3005;R.3005 Texturado;M3007;R.3007 Mate;3009R;R.3009;3011R;R.3011;S3011;R.3011 Satinado;3012R;R.3012;3013R;R.3013;3014R;R.3014;3015R;R.3015;3016R;R.3016;3017R;R.3017;3018R;R.3018;3020R;R.3020;3022R;R.3022;3024R;R.3024;3026R;R.3026;3027R;R.3027;3028R;R.3028;3031R;R.3031;3032R;R.3032;3033R;R.3033;4001R;R.4001;4002R;R.4002;4003R;R.4003;4004R;R.4004;4005R;R.4005;4006R;R.4006;4007R;R.4007;4008R;R.4008;4009R;R.4009;4010R;R.4010;4011R;R.4011;4012R;R.4012;5000R;R.5000;S5000;R.5000 Satinado;5001R;R.5001;5002R;R.5002;S5002;R.5002 Satinado;5003R;R.5003;M5003;R.5003 Mate;SJ803;R.5003 Mate SJ803G;S5003;R.5003 Satinado;5004R;R.5004;5005R;R.5005;S5005;R.5005 Satinado;T5005;R.5005 Texturado;5007R;R.5007;5008R;R.5008;M5008;R.5008 Mate;S5008;R.5008 Satinado;5009R;R.5009;S5009;R.5009 Satinado;S5010;R.5010 Satinado;5011R;R.5011;S5011;R.5011 Satinado;T5011;R.5011 Texturado;5012R;R.5012;M5012;R.5012 Mate;S5012;R.5012 Satinado;5013R;R.5013;M5013;R.5013 Mate;T5013;R.5013 Texturado;5014R;R.5014;M5014;R.5014 Mate;S5014;R.5014 Satinado;5015R;R.5015;5017R;R.5017;5018R;R.5018;5019R;R.5019;M5019;R.5019 Mate;5020R;R.5020;S5020;R.5020 Satinado;5021R;R.5021;S5021;R.5021 Satinado;5022R;R.5022;M5022;R.5022 Mate;5023R;R.5023;M5023;R.5023 Mate;S5023;R.5023 Satinado;5024R;R.5024;M5024;R.5024 Mate;S5024;R.5024 Satinado;T5024;R.5024 Texturado;5025R;R.5025;5026R;R.5026;6000R;R.6000;6001R;R.6001;6002R;R.6002;6003R;R.6003;6003M;R.6003 Mate;S6003;R.6003 Satinado;6004R;R.6004;M6005;R.6005 Mate;S6005;R.6005 Satinado;SKA05;R.6005 Tex. SKA05 F;T6005;R.6005 Texturado;6006R;R.6006;M6006;R.6006 Mate;6007R;R.6007;6008R;R.6008;M6009;R.6009 Mate;S6009;R.6009 Satinado;SKA09;R.6009 Tex. SKA09;T6009;R.6009 Texturado;6010R;R.6010;6011R;R.6011;S6011;R.6011 Satinado;6012R;R.6012;M6012;R.6012 Mate;6013R;R.6013;M6013;R.6013 Mate;6014R;R.6014;6015R;R.6015;M6015;R.6015 Mate;6016R;R.6016;6017R;R.6017;6018R;R.6018;6019R;R.6019;M6019;R.6019 Mate;T6019;R.6019 Texturado;6020R;R.6020;6021R;R.6021;M6021;R.6021 Mate;S6021;R.6021 Satinado;TC558;R.6021 Texturado;6022R;R.6022;6024R;R.6024;T6024;R.6024 Texturado;6025R;R.6025;6026R;R.6026;6027R;R.6027;6028R;R.6028;6029R;R.6029;6032R;R.6032;TC559;R.6032 Tex. C559;6033R;R.6033;6034R;R.6034;6035R;R.6035;6036R;R.6036;7000R;R.7000;T7000;R.7000 Texturado;7001R;R.7001;T7001;R.7001 Texturado;7002R;R.7002;7003R;R.7003;7004R;R.7004;7004T;R.7004 Texturado;7005R;R.7005;M7005;R.7005 Mate;S7005;R.7005 Satinado;7006R;R.7006;M7006;R.7006 Mate;S7006;R.7006 Satinado;T7006;R.7006 Texturado;7008R;R.7008;7009R;R.7009;M7009;R.7009 Mate;7010R;R.7010;M7010;R.7010 Mate;M7011;R.7011 Mate;S7011;R.7011 Satinado;M7012;R.7012 Mate;S7012;R.7012 Satinado;7012T;R.7012 Texturado;7013R;R.7013;7015R;R.7015;M7015;R.7015 Mate;S7015;R.7015 Satinado;7015T;R.7015 Texturado;YL315;R.7015 YL315F AKZO NOBEL;C185A;R.7016 C-185 AZKO NOBEL;SL816;R.7016 C453-7016-SL816G;M7016;R.7016 Mate;S7016;R.7016 Satinado;SLA16;R.7016 Tex. SLA16F;TIG16;R.7016 TEXT. (TIGER 029/7/289);T7016;R.7016 Texturado;16211;R.7016-211.7016;7021R;R.7021;M7021;R.7021 Mate;S7021;R.7021 Satinado;7021T;R.7021 Texturado;M7022;R.7022 Mate;S7022;R.7022 Satinado;7022T;R.7022 Texturado;7023R;R.7023;M7023;R.7023 Mate;7024R;R.7024;M7024;R.7024 Mate;S7024;R.7024 Satinado;T7024;R.7024 Texturado;7026R;R.7026;7030R;R.7030;M7030;R.7030 Mate;S7030;R.7030 Satinado;T7030;R.7030 Texturado;7031R;R.7031;M7031;R.7031 Mate;S7031;R.7031 Satinado;T7031;R.7031 Texturado;7032R;R.7032;M7032;R.7032 Mate;S7032;R.7032 Satinado;T7032;R.7032 Texturado;7033R;R.7033;S7033;R.7033 Satinado;7034R;R.7034;M7034;R.7034 Mate;7035R;R.7035;M7035;R.7035 Mate;S7035;R.7035 Satinado;RT703;R.7035 Tex. RT-7035;T7035;R.7035 Texturado;7036R;R.7036;S7036;R.7036 Satinado;T7036;R.7036 Texturado;7037R;R.7037;M7037;R.7037 Mate;S7037;R.7037 Satinado;T7037;R.7037 Texturado;7038R;R.7038;M7038;R.7038 Mate;S7038;R.7038 Satinado;T7038;R.7038 Texturado;21170;R.7038-2117038;7039R;R.7039;039FT;R.7039 FT QUARTZ Fine Texture;M7039;R.7039 Mate;S7039;R.7039 Satinado;T7039;R.7039 Texturado;7040R;R.7040;M7040;R.7040 Mate;S7040;R.7040 Satinado;T7040;R.7040 Texturado;7042R;R.7042;M7042;R.7042 Mate;7043R;R.7043;M7043;R.7043 Mate;7043T;R.7043 Texturado;7044R;R.7044;M7044;R.7044 Mate;7044S;R.7044 Satinado;7044T;R.7044 Texturado;7045R;R.7045;7045S;R.7045 Satinado;7045T;R.7045 Texturado;7046R;R.7046;7047R;R.7047;M7047;R.7047 Mate;S7047;R.7047 Satinado;7048R;R.7048;8000R;R.8000;8001R;R.8001;8002R;R.8002;S8002;R.8002 Satinado;8003R;R.8003;M8003;R.8003 Mate;S8003;R.8003 Satinado;RT800;R.8003 Tex. RT-8003 F;T8003;R.8003 Texturado;8004R;R.8004;T8004;R.8004 Texturado;M8007;R.8007 Mate;S8007;R.8007 Satinado;8008R;R.8008;M8008;R.8008 Mate;8011R;R.8011;M8011;R.8011 Mate;T8011;R.8011 Texturado;8012R;R.8012;S8012;R.8012 Satinado;M8014;R.8014 Mate;19266;R.8014 Sat SM775L;8014S;R.8014 Satinado;RT814;R.8014 Tex. SMA14 F;TIG14;R.8014 TEXT. (TIGER 029/60488);T8014;R.8014 Texturado;8015R;R.8015;8016R;R.8016;M8016;R.8016 Mate;S8016;R.8016 Satinado;M8017;R.8017 Mate;S8017;R.8017 Satinado;RT801;R.8017 Tex. RT-8017;T8017;R.8017 Texturado;M8019;R.8019 Mate;FR221;R.8019 M-FR C221;58LM1;R.8019 Sat. 58LM1F288S2;S8019;R.8019 Satinado;SM819;R.8019 SM819G;SM319;R.8019 TEXT. SM319G;T8019;R.8019 Texturado;8022R;R.8022;M8022;R.8022 Mate;T8022;R.8022 Texturado;8023R;R.8023;8024R;R.8024;8025R;R.8025;M8025;R.8025 Mate;S8025;R.8025 Satinado;8028R;R.8028;M8028;R.8028 Mate;8029R;R.8029;9001R;R.9001;M9001;R.9001 Mate;S9001;R.9001 Satinado;T9001;R.9001 Texturado;9002R;R.9002;M9002;R.9002 Mate;S9002;R.9002 Satinado;T9002;R.9002 Texturado;9003R;R.9003;S9003;R.9003 Satinado;9004R;R.9004;9005R;R.9005;M9005;R.9005 Mate;S9005;R.9005 Satinado;NC588;R.9005 Tex. C588;TIG05;R.9005 Tex. Tiger;T9005;R.9005 Texturado;9006R;R.9006;M9006;R.9006 Mate;S9006;R.9006 Satinado;SW166;R.9006 Satinado SW166D;T9006;R.9006 Texturado 29/90146;9007R;R.9007;S9007;R.9007 Satinado;TIG07;R.9007 Text. 029/90147;T9007;R.9007 Texturado;9010C;R.9010 Carta Ral;9010D;R.9010 Dupond;M9010;R.9010 Mate;S9010;R.9010 Satinado;RT910;R.9010 Tex. RT-9104;T9010;R.9010 Texturado;9011R;R.9011;S9011;R.9011 Satinado;9011T;R.9011 Texturado;9016R;R.9016;SA816;R.9016 C454-9016-SA816G;M9016;R.9016 Mate;S9016;R.9016 Satinado;ST016;R.9016 ST;T9016;R.9016 Texturado;9017R;R.9017;9018R;R.9018;S9018;R.9018 Satinado;9022R;R.9022;M9022;R.9022 Mate;SW253;R.9022 SW253F;9023R;R.9023;MMA03;R.Marron Text. (SXA03L);YL322;Ral 7022 YL322F;DB703;RAL ANTRACITA (029/80077);DS240;Ral Design 240 8005;19904;Ral Verde Texturado (YK330L/20);RERAL;Resto Ral;R5149;RF-5149-XW;R7105;RF-7105-XW;R7126;RF-7126-XW;R7147;RF-7147-WX;R7232;RF-7232-XW;R7625;RF-7625-XW;F9105;RF-9105-XW;R9813;RF-9813-XW;R9949;RF-9949-XW;R9961;RF-9961-XW;R6114;RM-6114-I;R6167;RM-6167-I;ROMAT;Rost.Matt 68/60116-TIGER;R100S;Rouge 100 Sable SW312F;RO220;Rouge 2200 Sable YX3101;FORES;RT-6009-Foresta;RT116;RT-7116-IT ADAPTA;RT119;RT-7119-I;R7236;RT-7236-I;7612I;RT-7612-I;8102I;RT-8102-I  ADAPTA;8107I;RT-8107-I  ADAPTA;8109A;RT-8109 Adapta;8115I;RT-8115-I ADAPTA;9104A;RT-9104 ADAPTA;X7131;RX-7131-IW;RX713;RX-7132-XW;RX719;RX-7198-XW;X7315;RX-7315-XW;X7319;RX-7319-XW;X7329;RX-7329-IW;X7330;RX-7330-XW;X7354;RX-7354-XW;X8112;RX-8112-XW;RX900;RX-9007-XW;RX994;RX-9945-XW;SABBI;Sabbia;SABSA;Sabbia Satinado;SATEX;Sabbia Tex. 13-21248-RT;SABTX;Sabbia Texturado;SA330;Sable 330;M350F;Sable Mars SX350F;SEALS;Sealskin;SGUGF;SGU-GRIS FORJA 402 (AKZO NOBEL);SIBER;Siberian RT-7119-I;SILVE;Silver 2525 YW206F;SLA71;SLA 71F;YX353;Starlight 2525 Sable YX353F;SWA01;SWA01JR AKZO;SWA52;SWA52L Negro Tex. Metal.;750OX;SY 750 OXI;TT765;Titan P12-T765;TX203;TX-2031 Akzo Nobel;21521;Verde 13-21521-RM;VERGR;Verde Granulado Technal;V2500;Vert 2500 Sable YW354F;V500S;Vert 500 Sable;VIRED;Vintage Red - SD031C3300520;VISON;Vison 2110104;YAZD2;YAZD 2525 SABLE YW370F;YK309;YK309F AKZO NOBEL')
```

Thanks!

Comment: I guess this is a `http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX` server config and if you can not change it: try to remove whitespaces and `\n` from the `@petition`

Comment: That´s not the problem because it works with the same @petition if I reduce the size of it. This will work: IIF(003050=0,''Base1;Base para foliar","BLANC;Blanco")

Comment: I wonder, you say via HTTParty, that you send a JSON, but the variable value you provided does not look like JSON...did I miss something?

Comment: If you check the headers you will see that I send the string like json.It does not look like a json but it will work like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution and the problem was not the length of the JSON. The problem was that in those long strings there are one "\ that breaks the hole petition.

In conclusion, HTTParty does not allow you to put \" in the variables that you send. The petition worked in Postman but can´t do it with HTTParty, I have also tried Faraday,Excon,HTTP,RestClient and the problem is the same in all of these gems.

Sorry, for my bad explanation in the question, by the way, thank´s everyone for your comments.